# Ensuring narrow dependency in Spark job when grouping on pre-partitioned data

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge Spark Dataset with columns A, B, C, D, E. Question is if I initially repartition on column A, and subsequently do two 'within-partition' groupBy operations:

```
**groupBy("A", "C")**....map(....).**groupBy("A", "E")**....map(....)
```

is Spark 2.0 clever enough to by-pass shuffling since both groupBy operations are 'within-partition' with respect to the parent stage - i.e. column A is included in both groupBy column specs? If not, what can I do to ensure a narrow dependency throughout the chain of operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark indeed supports optimization like this. You can check that by analyzing execution plan:

```
val df = Seq(("a", 1, 2)).toDF("a", "b", "c")

df.groupBy("a").max().groupBy("a", "max(b)").sum().explain
== Physical Plan ==
*HashAggregate(keys=[a#42, max(b)#92], functions=[sum(cast(max(b)#92 as bigint)), sum(cast(max(c)#93 as bigint))])
+- *HashAggregate(keys=[a#42, max(b)#92], functions=[partial_sum(cast(max(b)#92 as bigint)), partial_sum(cast(max(c)#93 as bigint))])
   +- *HashAggregate(keys=[a#42], functions=[max(b#43), max(c#44)])
      +- Exchange hashpartitioning(a#42, 200)
         +- *HashAggregate(keys=[a#42], functions=[partial_max(b#43), partial_max(c#44)])
            +- LocalTableScan [a#42, b#43, c#44]
```

As you can see there is only one exchange but two hash aggregates.